# Share page between routes NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router, vercel

I'm using the app folder and i have the following structure

```
/app
    /user
      /dashboard/page
      /route2/page
    /tutor
      /dashboard/page
      /route3/page
```

Under user and under tutor i have different routes but i need to share a couple of pages between the two path.
For example the dashboard page should be in common between the two routes.
I need to do so because if i make a change in one common page i would need to replicate the code in the other page.

Is there a way to do so in Next?
The alternative would be to place the common page under a common path but i don't like a user to navigate to

> /common/dashboard

and then to all the other user related routes under

> /user/...

How can i structure this? is there something i'm missing out?

Comment: I would refactor your route architecture to something like `/app/dashboard/page` This is the dashboard. Nothing less or more. `/app/user/.../page` and `/app/tutor/.../page`are user/tutor specific pages. Perhaps parallel routes and intercepting routes offer other possibilities. And you can refactor the `dashboard/page` as a component and import just the component to the page component. Many possibilities. Often it is better to describe what you want to achieve (the user experience) instead of presenting what you did (your route architecture).

Comment: I can comment on this : 

The site provides access to different types of user.
We have 
One time buyer user 
Subscription user
Tutor user ( a different kind of user )

They have access to different functionallities inside the website BUT they have some common pages.

I don't know if it's wrong to somehow switch from a /user/info to a /general/dashboard when the user navigates because the "dashboard" should be shared between different types of user

Comment: Understand. Thought so. I don't see any harm in sharing dashboards, user profiles  and other shared pages. It's more a question around (perhaps role based) authorization. If all have the same rights or almost the same rights, just go with one dashboard. If the rights differ, don't get too clever with using only one dashboard. I would prefer separate dashboards (routes) with shared components to avoid code duplication.